# Get sound to complete playing before using text to speech

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have a button that when pressed, I would like to have play a 'correct' sound before text to speech is used. However, while the text to speech starts before the 'correct' sound is done playing so the two sounds are overlapping. How can I start text to speech once the 'correct' sound is done playing? Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!!

```
public void onClick(View view){

        Button btn = (Button) view;
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.animal_text);
        textViewString = tv.getText().toString();
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correct);

        if (btn.getText().equals(textViewString)) {

            mp.start();

            Resources res = getResources();
            String[] myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.englishAnimalArray);
            String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            tv.setText(q);
            textViewString = tv.getText().toString();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                tts.speak(textViewString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            } else {
                tts.speak(textViewString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've used `requestAudioFocus` to pause music, use tts, then resume music, it might be helpful to you https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look in the API Guide? What about the Callback setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener) (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Callbacks)?

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
     /* Implement the needed functionality */
});
```